# Messenger and Facebook photo access privacy

Tags: privacy, mobile, permissions

Does turning on "photo access permissions" for the Messenger or Facebook app on IOS/Android allow them to download the whole phone's photo gallery on Facebook’s servers? Do they do that?

Comment: It does allow them. Whether they do that or not depends on whether your trust them to do it, for whatever reason they may justify the need

Answer (score 1):

First, look up what the permissions mean from the developers: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en - yes, it looks like it would be possible for an app to access the entire photo store on your device.

Second, think about the impacts of your suggestion. If you have 100 GB of photos on your device, then that would mean that the app would have to *transfer* all those files. This would become very evident when you max out your transfer limits. It is also possible for users to see what data bandwidth an app uses. If Facebook was doing this type of transfer, it would be the top app for data use, and questions would be asked.

So, is it likely that all the photos are downloaded? No. If they tried it, the public would notice and it would make the news.

There is little benefit for Facebook to do this and huge problems if they tried it.

Comment: They wouldn't download them for the reasons you outline, but they can definitely hash them and/or apply a face detection algorithm on the device itself, to extract identifying info while being lightweight enough to transmit.